# Relation between DFT filter bank and sliding DFT

Tags: dft, filter-bank

I am reading the book 'spectral audio signal processing'. It says when $n=LN-1$ for any integer $L$, the sliding DFT

$$X_n(k)=\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}x(n+m)e^{-j2\pi mk/N}$$

coincides with the DFT filter bank.

But at other times, they differ by a linear phase term. See [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/DFT_Filter_Bank_I.html) for the details.

1. I cannot figure out why the above holds.

P.S., the DFT filter bank expression is given in [this link.](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/System_Diagram_Running_Sum_Filter.html)

2. Another question is:
   In what situation can sliding DFT be used? Is it only meaningful for theoretical analysis?

Can you help with the above questions?